# i am creating the food menu in android and would like to display to menu lunch and dinner within different timespan.

Tags: java, android

If time is between 11:30 am to 1:30 pm then i would like to display lunch menu and if the time is between 5.30 pm to 10.30 pm then i would like to display dinner menu.

```
 Calendar currTime = Calendar.getInstance();
 int hour = currTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int min = currTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

 if(hour >=11 && hour <= 14)
        {
              if(min >= 30 || min <=30) {
                  foodArrayList = getModel();
                  menu.setText("Lunch Menu");
              }
        }
        else //if ((hour >= 17 && min >= 30) || (hour <= 23 && min <= 30))
        if(hour >=17 && hour <= 23)
        {
           if(min >= 30 || min <=30){
               foodArrayList = getModel1();
               menu.setText("Dinner Menu");
           }

        }
        else
        {
           foodArrayList = getModel2();
            menu.setText("We are Closed!!");
            Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
            startActivity(myintent);

        }
```

Comment: What is your question? Does the program not work as intended? What happens when you run it?

Comment: `min >= 30 || min <= 30` will always be true, because a number is always either greater or less than 30.

Comment: I am getting the answer in the range  of 11am to 2.59 pm for lunch menu and from 5pm to 10.59pm for dinner menu. But not in proper time range  which is from 11.30 am to 2.30 pm and 5:30 pm to 10:30pm...i don't know how to set the minutes range to get proper timespan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two if conditions you should go with only one as the second if condition will always return true if you want to go with your logic.

Try the below logic:

```
   Calendar currTime = Calendar.getInstance();
         int hour = currTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int min = currTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        try {
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date lunchStart  = parser.parse("11:29");
        Date lunchStop   = parser.parse("13:31");
        Date dinnerStart = parser.parse("17:29");
        Date dinnerStop  = parser.parse("23:31");


            Date userDate = parser.parse(hour+":"+min);
            //for lunch
            if (userDate.after(lunchStart) && userDate.before(lunchStop)) {
                System.out.println("lunch");
            }
            else if (userDate.after(dinnerStart) && userDate.before(dinnerStop))
            {
                   System.out.println("dinner");
            }
            else{

                System.out.println("We are Closed!!");
            } 
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // Invalid date was entered
        }
```

You need to enter the current time in `userDate`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: its keep on printing "lunch" as an answer all the time

Comment: I only gave you the logic to write it on your own..
I have edited my answer with the time span you mentioned, rest of the BL you need to do it on your own.

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked. Actually i was confused about giving the current time in Userdate.